# Extending Function to Make it Continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I've been struggling with extending this function to make it continuous:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

So, the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Set of limit points of the domain is obviously $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem because none of the methods we've done in class work.
I'm not even sure how to a priori assume whether I can or can't extend this function to be continuous (or even in which points is it possible to do so).
This is all new to me so I would appreciate any help or advice on how to predict the behaviour of this function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a set y, does this function have a limit as x approaches 0 from the left? Does it have a limit as x approaches 0 from the right? Finding that out is the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to detail my ``elsewhere'' in the previous comment. Fix $y\neq 0$, then for $x<<1$ the argument of the sine is small thus it is comparable to the sine itself plus lower order terms $o(x)$, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right) \approx \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} +o(1)$$

As you send $x\to 0$ you get that it has as limit $0$, hence you can continuously extend to $(0,y)$ for all $y\neq 0$ by setting

$$f(x,y) = 0\,, \qquad \text{on $\{(0,y)\,:\, y\neq 0\}$}$$

As Guy Fasone example shows, at the origin this trick does not work.

---

By the way, the set of limit points at the origin is $[0,1]$, not the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Passing to polar coordinates you get

$$\frac{1}{\rho \cos \theta} \sin\left(\rho \cos^3 \theta \right) \approx cos^2 \theta$$

Answer (score 3):

This function cannot be extended continuously to the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, because there are points on the line $x=0$ such that your function $f$ approaches different limits from different directions.

For example, consider the point $P=(0,0)$, which does not lie in the domain of $f$, and consider the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches this point along the two lines $y=0$ and $y=x$. Clearly $f$ is defined at all points on these lines except $P$.

On the line $y=0$, $f(x,y)=f(x,0)=\frac{1}{x}sin(\frac{x^3}{x^2+0})=\frac{1}{x}sin(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x}$.

So using l'Hopitals rule, we see that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{cos(x)}{1}=cos(0)=1$.

Similarly, on the line $y=x$, $f(x,y)=f(x,x)=\frac{1}{x}sin(\frac{x^3}{x^2+x^2})=\frac{1}{x}sin(\frac{1}{2}x)$,

and again, using l'Hopital's rule, $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(\frac{1}{2}x)}{x}=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}cos(\frac{1}{2}x)}{1}=\frac{1}{2}cos(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

This proves that the limit of $f$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $P$ is undefined, and so $f$ cannot be extended continuously to the whole plane.

Comment: Shouldn't P just be a special case? Do you not need to prove the statement for points on the two axis which are different from $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: @DBoss: Nope.  The question is whether there is a continuous extension to the whole plane, i.e. an extension continuous at every point of the plane.  This answer proves that any extension would be discontinuous at $(0,0)$, and hence it is not the case that it is continuous on the whole plane.  In other words, this is a "for all" statement, and so finding a single counterexample disproves it.

Answer (score 1):

> You can either extend $f$ as follow 
>   $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right)& x\neq 0\\0&x=0 \end{cases}$$ or 
>   $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right)& x\neq 0\\1&x=0 \end{cases}$$ 
>   **Remark:** The first extension is continuous everywhere except at $(0,0)$ (see below) whereas the second is not continuous on $\{(0,y)\in\Bbb R^2\}.$

However, The function $f$ will never be continuously extended  at $(0,0)$
since,

For all $h\neq 0$ and we have, $$(h,0), (h,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
but, 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,0) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}= 1$$
and  for $y \neq 0$ near $h$ near zero we have,
 $$f(h,y) =\frac{1}{h}\sin\left(\frac{h^3}{h^2+y^2}\right) \sim\frac{h^2}{h^2+y^2}\to 0\neq 1$$

> **Continuity of the first extension on** $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$
>   This last line also prove that if $y_0\neq 0$ then 
>   $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,y_0)}f(x,y) = 0 = f(0,y_0)$$
>   which end the proof since naturally $f$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: OK, but what about other points? For $(0,0)$, it's always solveable somehow (at least for now I haven't had issues with that point), but I have problems solving for the rest.

Comment: Elsewhere can be continuously extended to $0$.

Comment: For the rest it ok such fucntions are continuous on their domain of defintion.

Comment: @G.S. have a look to the edit

Comment: As you send $h\to 0$ that thing drops to zero.. Hence you can extend it continuously to $0$ everywhere on $(0,y)$ but for $y=0$.

Comment: @G.S. Thanks for correcting but that is not extendable

Comment: @iskra see the edit and tell me whether thius answer your question . i have put two possible extention

Comment: @GuyFsone it does answer my question for the point $(0,0)$, but what about the other points? I still can't see if, for example, function could be extended for the point $(0,3)$ or $(0,0.5)$ or any other point of that form.

Comment: @iskra this extension$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right)& x\neq 0\\0&x=0 \end{cases}$$is continuous on $\Bbb R^2\setminus (0,0)$

Comment: @GuyFsone How can I prove it?

Comment: @GuyFsone the OP's question was on how to prove that statement for points $(0,y)$ where $y$ isn't $0$

Comment: @iskra see this passage: for $y \neq 0$ near $h$ near zero we have,  
 $$f(h,y) =\frac{1}{h}\sin\left(\frac{h^3}{h^2+y^2}\right) \sim\frac{h^2}{h^2+y^2}\to 0\neq 1$$

Comment: @DBoss this what the first extension precisely does.

Comment: @GuyFsone yeah but I mean, you extended the function, aren't you supposed to somehow prove that continuity?

Comment: The proof of the continuity is there. see the last limit

Comment: GuyFsone, how come that than you said to me it was not extendable ;p. @iskra check my own answer.

Comment: @G.S. read me correctly my answer is still there. I said f cannot be continuously extended at $(0,0)$. but the first extension I gave is continuous everwhere except at $(0,0)$ did I change something?

Comment: @iskra if you don't get it now then I give up see the edit.

Comment: Why a down vote here?